# Using Google Analytics in an Android app with both a UI Activity and a neverending background service

Tags: android, service, google-analytics, analytics

We have an Android app which consists of two main components:
The main UI (several activities) and a background service running endlessly without any direct interaction with the UI (both writing/reading from the same database). The UI is often used by the users but not that much. The background service should run at all times.

Currently we are using Flurry but we did it all wrong. Since events are coming from both the activities and the background service, it corrupted our session settings, active users and so forth. We want to make things better.

We've decided to replace Flurry with Google Analytics (SDK v3 improved a lot since the last time we examined it). We created two different properties with different tracking IDs (one for the UI and one for the service). Our plan is to use the EasyTracker with the UI (much simpler in measuring session times and screens flow) and use a manual tracker for the service (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced#multiple-trackers)

We have two main concerns:

1. Is it a good idea to separate the UI and the service into two different properties?
2. Should we measure session times for the service?  We do want to know how many users are actually running the service but session time is irrelevant in this case. Is there any other event we can use just to know how many active service users are there?

Any thoughts, remarks, suggestions or insights would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, Alik

Comment: Nobody encountered such a situation or is my question that stupid?